# Querying Complex Object using Lambda

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I am querying a complex c# object that describes a Shift Roster. This object is populated from a web service and is an object from a third party software supplier.

My task is to build a gridview from data from this third party product. The object is an that contains other objects nested inside most of which are an array of objects.

I am using Lambda Expressions to navigate down the object, but I am struggling to get values out, and I am also wondering whether the expression I am writing could be better. Here is one example where I am trying to get an employee name out:

```
var employeeDetails = employeeRoster.PathsRosters.SelectMany(a => a.EmployeesRosters);
                var empName = employeeDetails.Select(b => b.Resource.Name).ToList();
                foreach (string nam in empName)
                {
                    string var = nam;
                }
```

`employeeRoster` is the object that I get back from the web service and `PathRosters` is an array. Then I am querying the result again and casting to a List just to get back the employee name.

Is there a better way of doing this? Unfortunately, I cannot serialize to XML as I have been told it has to be done in memory on the object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of making two calls, you can do the same with one:

```
var employeeNames = employeeRoster.PathsRosters.SelectMany(a => a.EmployeesRosters)
     .Select(b => b.Resource.Name).ToList();
```

Also, your `foreach` loop doesn't do anything. I don't see the point in having this.

Comment: Hi - Yes, I have just managed to get this into one line, but to actually get the value returned, you need the foreach loop. Or is there another way just to return the value?

Comment: What are you trying to return? A List<string>, or a string? If a List<string> (which is a List or collection of string objects), then @gleng's answer will do it for you. If just a string, you might want to wrap it in `String.Join<string>(String.Empty, employeeNames);` to get a string.

Comment: @Andy5 Just `return employeeNames` in my example. It will return a `List<string>`.

Answer (score 0):

```
var empNames = employeeRoster.PathsRosters.SelectMany(a => a.EmployeesRosters)
     .Select(b => b.Resource.Name).ToList();
```